# Can functions passed to 'reselect' contain other selectors and functions and still preserve createSelector memoization benefits?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I understand the memoization concept behind 'reselect' and am using it to compose my Redux selectors, but I'm not entirely sure how `createSelector` "knows" when the component selectors' data has changed and whether including other function calls within those 'sub-selectors' interferes with `createSelector`'s memoization.

The issue is that within the 'sub-selectors', that is the functions I'm passing to `createSelector`, I need to perform some basic checking that the part of the JSON data tree isn't `unedefined` (I used `ramda` library for this) and also to *select* a portion of a JSON data tree by name.  That is, in the 'sub-selector' `getParksData` I am making calls to `existsAt` and `nameToBlockData`, which are in other modules.  (I know in the example below I'm only composing from one 'sub-selector'; I'll add others later).

Am I still maintaining all the memoization benefits of `createSelector` when I call other functions?  Do I need to somehow memoize those functions? Thanks for any info!

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import existsAt from '../../../utils/objectExistsAtPath';

import {
  nameToBlockData,
  HOME_DATA_FEATURE_PARKS,
} from '../../../api/json-name-to-block-data';

const R_BASE = 'home.data.blocks';


// eslint-disable-next-line
const getParksData = (state, position) => (existsAt(R_BASE,  state) ? nameToBlockData(state.home.data.blocks, HOME_DATA_FEATURE_PARKS).sub_blocks.find(element => element.position === position) : {});

export default createSelector(
  [getParksData],
  (parksData) => (parksData),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`createSelector` will compute all input selectors. If they have been created using `createSelector` they will also be memoized.

The memoization only checks the input arguments, so as long as your state (or sub-state) haven't changed you will still get the benefit of memoization.

Notice I'm calling `barSelector` twice but `getFoo` is executed only once

```js
const {
  createSelector
} = Reselect

const getFoo = (thing) => {
  console.log('getFoo')
  return thing.foo
}

const state = {
  foo: {
    bar: 1
  },
}

const fooSelector = state => getFoo(state)

const barSelector = createSelector(
  fooSelector,
  foo => foo.bar
)


console.log(barSelector(state))
console.log(barSelector(state))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
```